# What is the fastest way to obtain date,time and parse into string along with some other info?

Tags: c++, string, date, time, concatenation

I am writing a logger which is supposed to be very efficient and fast. The logging to a file is done on a separate thread but I would like to know how to efficiently form a string of date, time, string, and two numbers...

for instance...

120911|14:56:43.432123|Sensor A|4|132.4

I have tried using struct tm, but from my timestamps (running the code in a loop 100000 times) it takes an average of 300nsec. I would like to know if there is a faster way and also whether it is possible to get milliseconds and maybe even microseconds from that.

Lastly,

What is the fastest way to concatenate them into a string without having too much overhead, is sprintf the best way?

Thanks

Comment: nanoseconds are smaller than both microseconds and milliseconds.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the disk I/O that's the bottleneck? Have you profiled your code and is string concatenation really the part that slows it down the most?

Comment: agreed, it would be nice to have nanosecond precision, but not a necessity. How do I get it from the struct?

Comment: My for loop is surrounding just...
time_t now = time(0);
struct tm* t = localtime(&now);

Comment: Accessing a file 100000 times is going to be 100000 slower then concatenating date,time, etc. This sounds like a micro optimization

Comment: Well, there is a separate thread which is writing to the file, my main function is producing the string and adding it to the queue, the writer thread is busy writing to a file when there is something to write in the queue.

Comment: @user1075883: It's still going to be much, *much* slower than writing that data to the file. Your queue will be massively backlogged generating data.

Comment: for string concatenation...usually string1+=string2 is definitely faster than string1 = string1 + string2...

Answer (score 0):

When designing a file based logger, there are two main scenarios from optimization standpoint.

- Either the message will make it to the file
- Or it won't.

If a message needs to go to the file, and the file is not on a solid state disk, you can expect the disk speed to dominate the whole process.  You will have a difficult tradeoff between flushing to disk after every log line, which means that the time consumed while creating the log message will be negligible in all simple cases; or not flushing which means that you will lose the most valuable logs.  You will lose those from rare, hard-to-reproduce system or application crashes.
All widely used logging frameworks make flushing configurable, passing the decision to the application or even to its administrator.

If a message does not go to the file (because of, for example, current log level settings), it is essential for performance to determine this fact (compare the log levels) *before* the text of the log message (parameter formatting, timestamp formatting...) is constructed.
`snprintf` is fine, but make sure that you only invoke it when you will really need the formatted message.

Finally, it is tricky to get nanosecond precision.  It is also meaningless, because as you have already measured, it is a fraction of a single CPU instruction on your hardware; you would have to become very formal about which instant is the one to be timestamped.  You have a choice between using the system time (updated about 100 times per second, depending on your operating system), the [ticks](https://superuser.com/questions/101183/what-is-a-cpu-tick) value not synchronized with the real time, or the CPU timestamp counter.  The last method is in no way synchronized with or convertible to real time, so it is not really practical for your needs.  [Read here why](http://www.strchr.com/performance_measurements_with_rdtsc).

It is always better if you print the timestamps only in resolution that is *known* to you and where the value does not change substantially while the log message is being produced.